# Unix - Nested Loop. One loop to untar then another to inspect each file in directory

Tags: unix, shell, nested-loops

I'm trying to loop round a load of tar files and then move the extracted files into a new folder, inspect them and delete them before moving onto the next tar.

Code is below:

```
for i in *
do
  tar -zxvf $i 
  mv *TTF* encoded
  cd encoded
  for j in *
  do
    echo $j
  done

  rm -f *TTF*
  cd ..
done
```

When it gets to the nested loop, it asks if I want to display all x possibilities. Clearly something is going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest running the script with bash debugging on, i.e. `bash -x myscript.sh`. This will help you track down which command is causing the output you're seeing.

Comment: One thing is certainly wrong with this script: since `encoded` is in the current dir (at least after loop one), the outer loop will try to perform `tar xzvf` on it.

Comment: @larsmans: if the encoded directory only appeared during the first iteration, there'd be no problem; the `*` is evaluated before the first iteration starts.  Since the directory is not created during the loop shown, there is a problem.  It might be that the '*' should be replaced by '`"$@"`'.

Comment: @Leffler, you're right, my mistake. It might also be that `$i` and `$j` have to be double-quoted.

Answer (score 3):

Did you write this in a text editor, then try to paste it into a terminal, by any chance? Did you use tabs to indent the lines? If so, try changing tabs to spaces, or just save the file as a shell script and then run it.

(The tab key invokes completion, which displays the "display all x possibilities" message if there are lots of completions that match.)

Answer (score 0):

Run the 'cd' command and its following actions in a sub-shell, which means you don't have to do '`cd ..`'.  Also, it would probably be better to extract each tar file directly in the sub-directory.

```
for i in *.tar.gz
do
  mkdir encoded
  (
  cd encoded
  tar -zxvf ../$i 
  for j in *
  do
    echo $j
  done
  )
  rm -fr encoded
done
```

This assumes only that the tar file doesn't contain any names with '`..`' in the paths of the files, which is very uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

echo "Enter no of terms" read count for i in $(seq 1 $count) do t=`expr $i - 1` for j in $(seq $t -1 0) do echo -n " " done j=`expr $count + 1` x=`expr $j - $i` for k in $(seq 1 $x) do echo -n "* " done echo ""